# EFI partition need to be increased in size having ubuntu in dual mode with already install windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have ubuntu on already installed windows 10. EFI partition was less than the required one so i tried to increase it with the help of Gparted and Disk, but it gives an error. How to fix the problem.
x-special/nautilus-clipboard
copy
file:///home/salam/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202020-06-12%2015-20-18.png

Comment: Could you try uploading your screenshot again? Are you doing this from a live-usb? You won't be able to resize the efi partion while running from the hdd it is on, you need the drive to be unmounted for gparted to do it's thing.

Comment: Ok, I was trying from live HDD. Lets try from live-USB

Comment: I tried format to FAT32 from live-usb and as a result lose everything in UFI partition, how to restore it.

Comment: You need boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair now.